# How to send server sent event using .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, server-sent-events

In my application I have a requirement send push notifications to the mobile clients. I tried with firebase, but its not 100% accurately working. So I read several articles and got to know, there is an approach called server sent events to handle this kind of scenarios. But I couldn't find any good resource to learn this thing. as per the my knowledge .Net core not inbuild support SSE.

is there any library to deal with this problem? how can I use server sent events with .net core API. please give me at least good resource to learn this thing. please don't this question. coz I think this will be helped to everyone in future.

Comment: SSE isn't meant for mobile clients. It's one alternative to send notifications to connected browsers in general. You can't send notifications to a browser that isn't even running.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can u please more explain this sir, which means I can't send notification to the mobile apps using .net SSE api?

Comment: ASP.NET Core supports push notifications through [SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-6.0) which uses WebSockets where possible and falls back to SSE and long polling if a WebSocket connection isn't possible. You can use SignalR both in browsers and applications. You don't find a lot of documentation about SSEs specifically because people are using WebSockets instead

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is it good to use websockets than SSE. isn't that costly than SSE?